# Importing LAS files in QGIS with LAStools gives an 'ascii encode error'

Tags: qgis, lidar, ascii, las, lastools

I'm new to QGIS environment and I am trying to load LAS files into QGIS with `lasground` but when I run the following process an error occurs:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0105' in position 68:
>   ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details

The LAS file must be correct because I can load and view it on ArcGIS program.

This is what the log says:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem? I'm using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Might be a non ascii character in your file path.

Comment: what does the log file show? "See log for more details “

Comment: Did it work when you ran it the first time and when re-running it from the history dialog it complained? It looks like a bug in processing when executing algorithms from the history dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All directory names and all file names must be free of spaces and other special symbols and cannot be Unicode characters. Only good old ASCII file and directory names are supported by [LAStools](http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools) at the moment.